# Octave + GNUPlot + Aquaterm + Mac OS 10.6

Tags: macos, unix, osx-snow-leopard, octave

I'm attempting to do all of my MatLab based homework assignments in Octave - the opensource representation of MatLab.

However, I'm having problems getting graphs to plot and I think it's a simple linking problem. I am running: 
-Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6)
-Octave 3.2.2
-Aquaterm 1.0.1
-GNUPlot 4.0

Here is an example of the errors that I am getting from my shell:

```
Mr-Buffalo:~ buffingtonr$ gnuplot 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libaquaterm.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap


octave-3.2.2:1> f = inline('x^2')

f(x) = x^2

octave-3.2.2:5> ezplot(f)
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libaquaterm.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libaquaterm.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
error: you must have gnuplot installed to display graphics; if you have gnuplot installed in a non-standard location, see the 'gnuplot_binary' function
octave-3.2.2:6>
```

I don't have the unix foundation necessary to trouble shoot this. Any suggestions/fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem could be related to this 
http://macresearch.org/gnuplot-aquaterm-snow-leopard-1061
in the answer:  Fri, 2009-09-18 01:59 — TeGa

Answer (score 1):

You have aquaterm 1.0.**1** installed, and gnuplot is referencing 1.0.**0**, which you apparently do not have installed on your system.

I'm not terribly familiar with installing a library on a Mac, but you might be able to just grab the 1.0.0 .dmg file from [the Aquaterm files page on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aquaterm/files/).

Alternatively, the newest version of octave or gnuplot might reference the newer library, so you might be able to just upgrade one of those instead.

---

It's a real hack, but I saw a couple places (including [this mailing list](http://www-old.cae.wisc.edu/pipermail/help-octave/2006-October/001881.html)) suggesting you just link 1.0.0 to your 1.0.1 library.  This isn't usually acceptable, because there's no guarantee the libraries are cross-compatible.  It would at least be a quick fix so you can get your homework done in time!

Answer (score 1):

### New Progress

When I investigated '/usr/local/lib/', I found that there was a symbolic-link in the directory:

```
aquaterm-1.0.0 -> /Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework/Versions/A/AquaTerm
```

So I created a similar sym-link to make the file gnuplot is looking for (...1.0.1) point to the default AquaTerm location:

```
aquaterm-1.0.1 -> /Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework/Versions/A/AquaTerm
```

This fixes the gnuplot launching issue. I verified that gnuplot **successfully** plots on its own by plotting a function:

```
Terminal type set to 'x11'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
```

---

### Now I get new **errors** in **Octave**:

```
octave-3.2.2:7> ezplot(f=inline('sin(x)'))

gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1"
                      ^
         line 0: You can't change the terminal in multiplot mode


gnuplot> if (exists("GPVAL_TERM")) print GPVAL_TERM; else print NaN
                    ^
         line 0: invalid expression 

error: Invalid call to strcat.  Correct usage is:

 -- Function File:  strcat (S1, S2, ...)
```

**However,** I have verified that gnuplot 4.0 is installed and does, in fact, plot graphs. So now it seems the error is in the communication between Octave and GNUPlot. I will try updating to a newer version of gnuplot if possible and report back.

-Buffalo

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**Step 1:** 
Replace /Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework with /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/AquaTerm.framework. This will ensure that the correct 64 bit AquaTerm libraries get referenced by the gnuplot compilation

**Step 2:** 
Replace /Applications/AquaTerm.app with /Applications/MacPorts/AquaTerm.app. This will ensure that the correct 64-bit AquaTerm binary is in the correct location

source: 
http://slashusr.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/gnuplot-with-aquaterm-on-osx-snow-leopard/